# Plotting transformed data

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I'm currently running some simple linear regressions to compare predicted animal movements (time spent in a movement/behaviour) with ground truth information of movement.

I have transformed the raw data for the regression analysis to get statistics such as model R2.

Question - is it ok to plot the raw data with a fitted regression line for visual representation given that the raw data were transformed for the actual analysis? As often happens, the raw data are more interpretable than the transformed data.

I see a similar question here but I don't think it addresses this: [Plotting raw data, but running statistics on log-transformed data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115804/plotting-raw-data-but-running-statistics-on-log-transformed-data)

Comment: If the raw data are more informative than the transformed data, why perform the transformation?

Comment: The absolute values are more meaningful (interpretable) - they are measures of behaviour. Also given small sample size a transformation may be needed.

Comment: What does a small sample size have to do with anything? Something about normality?

Comment: If the transformation is on a log scale, you could plot the axes on a log transform.

Comment: Normality violation was my thought. @AdamO, yes log. This is an option but my worry is the interpretability of the axes thereafter.

Comment: @FfermR many readers confuse themselves trying to interpret log transformed axes. On the other hand, you are right to expect your readers to have a sufficiently adequate technical edge to read and understand what you are presenting. If you are publishing to an ecology journal and need more than a sentence to justify a log transform, it's probably not a very good journal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @AdamO. I take it that plotting the raw data is not justified then.